# How to convert a map into a table and export as a new doc?

Tags: printing, clojure, hashmap, output

I have a large .txt file (~7000 characters) containing a map written in the following format

> [{:lat 42.156111, :lon 77.603889, :name "lake Issyk Kul (presumably
>   Barskon)", :source "Russian data 1339-1784 from (1) Melikishvili and
>   (2) John T Alexander", :year 1339} {:lat 47.169, :lon 47.45, :name
>   "Sarai", :source "Russian data 1339-1784 from (1) Melikishvili and (2)
>   John T Alexander", :year 1345} ....].

I would like to convert this text file into a table with proper columns and rows and then export that table into a new text file.

So far I have been using (print-table [read-string (slurp "/path/to/file")]) to get the table, but am not sure how to redirect this table output into a new document.

I am new to Clojure and am unsure if it is possible to do all of this at once, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(spit "aaa.txt" 
   (with-out-str
      (clojure.pprint/print-table (read-string data))))
```